# Limiting behavior of a meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Refer the following answer.

[image]
[image]
Can someone explains how can this follows from Morera's theorem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd argue you are using both Morera's Theorem *and* it's converse - since we have $g$ analytic in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\},$ given any $C \subset \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ we have $\int_C g = 0.$ We then consider any curve going through the origin and deform it slightly away from the origin; we must get a zero integral by the prior result, so by taking the limits any path in $\mathbb C$ has zero integral so $g$ is analytic by Morera's Theorem. Now, this is way more complicated a proof than you need to use, as Kavi notes below.

Answer (score 4):

The proof is unnecessarily long and complicated. First of all Morera's Theorem is used only to get an entire function $g$ and you can do this without Morera's Theorem also. Just use the power series expansion.

Note that $g(z) \to 0$ as $ |z| \to \infty$. This implies that $g$ is a bounded entire function. By Louiville's Theorem $g$ is a constant. But then  $f(z)=az+b$  for some $a$ and $b$ and the hypothesis implies that $a=0$.